# Getting Sequel associations through Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sequel

I'm trying to return json-formatted data from my Sinatra REST API. I currently have a bunch of associations set up, but I'm having trouble getting the views I want from my API despite getting them easily in Ruby.

For example, from my tables:

```
DB.create_table?(:calendars) do
  primary_key :id

end

DB.create_table?(:schedules) do
  primary_key :id

  foreign_key :resource_id,  :resources
  foreign_key :task_id, :tasks
  foreign_key :calendar_id,  :calendars
end
```

In Ruby, I'm able to run a block like this and display all the info I need through my associations:

```
Calendar.each do |c|
  c.schedules.each do |s| 
    puts "RESOURCE ##{s.resource_id}"
    s.tasks.each do |t|
      p t
    end
    puts
  end
end
```

the `c.schedules` call works because my `calendar` model contains a `one_to_many :schedules` association.

Now, I'm wondering how this translates to my Sinatra API. In my simple `GET` route, I've tried many variations trying to get the schedules associated with a calendar, and convert it to JSON:

```
get '/calendars' do
    c = DB[:calendar].first
    c.schedules.to_json
    content_type :json
end
```

... but I'll end up with an error like `undefined method 'schedules' for {:id=>1}:Hash`

So it looks like it's returning a hash here, but I've tried a bunch of stuff and haven't figured out how I'm supposed to work with my associations in Sinatra. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your first block works but the second doesn't is because in the first case, you're using a Sequel **model instance** of class `Calendar`, whereas in the second case you're using a Sequel **`dataset`**.

When you iterate over `Calendar.each do |c|`, the `c` variable gets populated with an instance of a `Calendar` class Sequel model object. This object has relationship methods defined (`one_to_many`) and you're able to query `schedules` and run other model methods on it.

However, `c = DB[:calendar].first` gets you a [Sequel dataset](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/dataset_basics_rdoc.html). This object is different than a model instance, it returns a standard Ruby hash (or an array of hashes).

You can change your 2nd block to use a model instead and it will get the result you want:

```
get '/calendars' do
    c = Calendar.first # <=== CHANGE FROM DATASET TO MODEL
    c.schedules.to_json
    content_type :json
end
```